# C# Convert List<object> to list<hashtable>

Tags: c#, list, object, hashtable

This is my first question here, so sorry for any wrong information or about my English.

I need to convert a `List<Object>` to `List<Hashtable>`

```
string IdsLista = string.Empty;
foreach (DataRow rows in ListaItensTransferencia.Rows)
{
    IdsLista += Convert.ToString(rows["Id Bem"]) + ",";
}
string[] idsSelecionadosListaTransferencia = IdsLista.Split(',');
List<object> listaIdsSelecionadosListTransferencia = new List<object>(idsSelecionadosListaTransferencia.Length);
listaIdsSelecionadosListTransferencia.AddRange(idsSelecionadosListaTransferencia);
wuc_itensTransferencia.checkBoxGrid = listaIdsSelecionadosListTransferencia;

//v this is the list<hashtable>                    v this is the list<object>                 
wuc_itensTransferencia.ItensSelecionados = listaIdsSelecionadosListTransferencia;
```

How do I do this ?

Comment: Make it a list of hashtables in the first place: `List<HashTable> listaIdsSelecionadosListTransferencia = new List<HashTable>();` but I think you will have problems since the contents of the list are strings, not hashtables.

Comment: Right now it looks like you've got a list of strings.  How do you expect to convert that to a list of hash tables?

Comment: Your variable names gives me headaches.

Comment: As D Stanley said, in order to do that conversion, the types need to be convertible in the first place. String is not convertible (implicitly or explicitly) to a hash table.

Comment: You probably want to use .Select(listItem => Convert.ToHashTable(listItem)) to convert your list, however Convert.ToHashTable doesn't exist so you'd have to figure out converting a single string to a single hash table first

Comment: Variables in .NET should always be named in English.  If you are using a Spanish-based programming language, feel free to name your variables in Spanish then.

Comment: hm thank you guys, i'm new in programming, i will try convert this string first

Comment: HashTable became obsolete like a decade ago.  You should be using a `Dictionary` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting data into list of object, put directly into list of hashtable. Why you want to create the comma separated string. Try this

```
    List<HashTable> hashTable = new List<HashTable>();
    foreach (DataRow rows in ListaItensTransferencia.Rows)
    {
        hashTable.Add(new HashTable("Id Bem", Convert.ToString(rows["Id Bem"])));
    }
```